# Maven renames jar when it downloads from central repository

Tags: java, maven, jar

When I try to build a project using `mvn clean install` command,
Maven downloads the new jar available and renames it ( renames it to `jar-name.jar.lastUpdated`).

So when the next module tries to build, it fails saying jar not found.
I need to modify the the jar name to remove the extension from it.

What causes to rename the jar and how can I avoid it?

`Update`: As stated by @ShmulikKlein below and the the link he provided;
it is being caused due to Maven not able to download the jar

Comment: Something in your configuration must be adding the updatedjar extension. Post your pom.xml.

Comment: @Tunaki I did try to look into pom.xml to check if there is anything like updatejar, there is nothing like that.
I am afraid being a corporate project won't be able to post the file.

Comment: Is this the exact extension or maybe the extension is `.lastUpdated` ?

Comment: @ShmulikKlein yeah its jarname.jar.lastUpdated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is an indication that Maven failed to download the artifact. Those files sets the time interval for the next attempt. Check your connection and settings. For Spring artifacts I would suggest to add Spring's repository to your `settings.xml` or POMs files.

Use the `-U` command line flag to force Maven to download the artifacts regardless of the time restriction.

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4673

Comment: Thanks for the info. I believe it's not able to update / find the jar in central repository